# App can't run on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to test an app built with Titanium Appcelerator on an Android emulator. After trying almost every possible solution I've seen here in SO and in the bug reports for Appcelerator I give up.

Whenever I try to run an app on the Android Emulator I get the following:

> [INFO] :   Running: C:\android-sdk-win\tools\emulator.exe "-avd" "4 WVGA (Nexus S)" "-port" "5554" "-no-boot-anim" "-partition-size" "128"
>
> [DEBUG] :  Ignoring C:***\FaveBooks\Resources\android
>
> [DEBUG] :  Ignoring C:***\FaveBooks\Resources\mobileweb
>
> **[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1**

If you take a look at the diagnostic log below it says that the JRE version is 1.7.0_51, although when I run `java -version` it returns `java version "1.6.0_45"`. Could than be the problem?

This happens when I run the android emulator with every possible device, and with every Android API version, I tested 4.4.2 (19), 4.1.2 (16), 4.0 (14), 3.2 (13), 2.3.3 (10), and 2.2 (8) *They are all currently installed*.

It happens with a basic app I created for testing and the sample apps they provide. All of them compile with Alloy without problems, so I think the problem is with the Android emulator.

---

Diagnostic log: (*Relevant parts, comment if you need more*)

> - Host OS: Windows 7
> - OS Version: 6.1
> - OS Arch: x86
> - JRE Version: 1.7.0_51
> - JRE Vendor: Oracle Corporation
> - JRE Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
> - Titanium Studio Version: 3.2.1.201402041146
> - Titanium SDK Version: 3.2.2.GA
> - SDK Modules API Version:2

<sup>I have also posted this as a bug report on [jira.appcelerator.org](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-3957), although it is mostly the same information I have posted here.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Process exit value was 1" 
is well know error, but they are many solution which work/Or not.

Be sure you have Titanium studio AND Titanium SDK up to date. if it's ok , using the version 7 of Java is OK and correct.

did you change in your tiapp.xml :

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

by

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>15</tool-api-level> 
</android>
```

i'm using 15 because i run on android 4.0.3 .Change it depends the version u want to use.

Finally, if you still have this message, try to go in

windows->preferences->studio->plateform->Android
click on Manage AVDs. be sure you have a correct AVD configure.
also check with rightclick on your project , properties, run/debug settings and be sure a correct emulator is in.

if the click isn't effective, you may have forgot a step in the instalation : 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK

Comment: The solution was to configure the AVD, I didn't create any new AVDs before trying. Thanks.